# Rails Cucumber URL hosts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, localhost, cucumber

So... I have this URL: example.com
which works in my browser, cause in my hosts file i have it set to

```
127.0.0.1   example.com
```

And that works in my browser... but not in cucumber.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

needed to change The Given I am on step definition to

```
Given /^(?:|I )am on (.+)$/ do |page_name|
host! "cucumber.example.com"
visit path_to(page_name)
end
```